# Transform LMI problem into different SDP form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I am trying to transform a LMI problem of the following form:

$ min_x \quad c^Tx \\ s.t. \quad x_1A_1+\dots+x_nA_n \preceq R$

into another SDP formulation:

$ min_x \quad c^Tx \\ s.t. \quad Ax = b, \quad X \preceq 0$

where x=vec(X) obtained by stacking the columns of X.
Thank you!

**Initial Idea:**

1. Introduce slack variable S.
2. Replace LMI constraint by:

$ x_1A_1+\dots+x_nA_n - R = S, \quad S \preceq 0$

3. Augment the decision variable x --> $\tilde{x}=[x,s]^T$.
4. Replace c by $\tilde{c}=[c,0]^T$.

But then I dont know how to continue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I edited the post

Comment: I am certain we have answered this before, but search fails me.

Comment: Ah, here we go: [Convert Semidefinite program forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732658/convert-semidefinite-program-forms)